# Maintaining lazy modularity in a monadic computation

Tags: haskell

So an argument for laziness is that it allows a better separation of concerns. If I know how to provide data, I shouldn't just assume that the user of that data needs some finite chunk of it. Laziness allows me to produce an infinite list and then defer the processing/cutting of if to the consumer.

I would like to extend this idea to also include monadic effects. This is the code I have

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Writer

longComputation :: Writer [String] [Int]
longComputation = do
    let list = iterate (+1) 0
    mapM (\n -> tell [show n] >> return n) list

twoSmallComputations :: Writer [String] [Int]
twoSmallComputations = do
    first <- fmap (take 10) longComputation
    second <- fmap (take 10) longComputation
    return $ first ++ second

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let (res, log') = runWriter twoSmallComputations
    mapM_ print res
```

You can see that the logging is "coupled" with the production of the result. In the `main` function I'm printing the result of the two smaller computations that each just take a piece of the infinite one. This works as expected and I get two sets of numbers from 0 to 9 as output.

Now, if I change the last line to `mapM_ print log'`, I don't get the same output. Instead I get an infinite listing of numbers.
Now, I understand why this works how it does so I'm looking for a different approach.

Is there any way to tie the effect tighter to the actual data produced so that it also gets cut? Because as things are at the moment I have to regress back from `... -> m [a]` functions to `... -> Int -> m [a]` ones.

Comment: Which result do you expect from `mapM_ print log'` instead?

Comment: The same thing I get from res.

Comment: Presumably you'd have to run your writers separately, and then do something like `map snd (zip res log)`, if you want a "cutoff".

Comment: @Mauris This does work but only because I can run the writer. It doesn't work for monads in general. If it's impossible for monads in general then make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: On "the same thing I get from res", note that it is only thanks to an arbitrary choice of yours that for every `n` in `res` there is a corresponding `show n` piece of string in the log - you could be logging anything else instead. Therefore, the only place in which you can tightly couple log and result is in `longComputation`; otherwise, the horse has already bolted. Also note that it is rigorously impossible, as a consequence of the first functor law, for `fmap` to modify the effects in a functor/applicative/monad.

Comment: @duplode I get that, but it doesn't matter if I log one or a thousand things per number. The point is that the logs are not truncated at all. As soon as I try using my infinite monadic computation I can only salvage the results of it. I can't do anything with the effects because they just go on forever.

Comment: But you can truncate the log, either in `longComputation` or in `main` (as Marius suggested). What you can't do is truncating the log (i.e. modifying the effects) just by changing the values within the functor (e.g. cutting the result list with `fmap`).

Comment: @duplode Again, yes. I know I can truncate the log. I can run the Writer and do what ever I want with it's results AND it's log. That's why I tried to stick to general names like "monadic effect" and "monadic computation". There are a ton more effects that have nothing to do with logging. What if I, for example had a state that I incremented by 1 for each value produced in the result? I can't run that by itself because the effect part would never compute, [continued]

Comment: yet I can write a perfectly simple function that instead of producing an infinite list, produces a list of fixed size and then use that a I wish. It feels like it should be possible to write infinite computations and still be able to actually use them WITHOUT escaping the monad in question.

Comment: I get we are talking about the general case. We run into the same issue with `fmap (take 10) $ sequence (fmap print [1..])`. The problem is that a chain of sequenced effects is not like a mapped-over list, that we can chop lazily at will, but closer to a fold, in which the whole depends on each part (in fact, `mapM_` is literally a fold, as `Data.Foldable` shows).

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure if it will clarify things or confuse them even more, but you might find streaming libraries such as `pipes` or `conduit` interesting. (Here is the [pipes tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.5/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html), a nice starting point). As far as I understand, something like `pipes` doesn't really affect this issue, but "merely" (sic!) states things in a more elegant and tractable way.

Comment: @duplode Thanks for the info. Again, if you'd like to make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want streams with effects that are only performed to the extent values are demanded from the stream, the you're best off with a streaming library, like [`pipes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) or [`conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit). For example, your code in `pipes` could look like this:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

ints :: Monad m => Producer Int m r
ints = go 0 where go n = yield n >> go (n + 1)

longComputation :: MonadWriter [String] m => Producer Int m r
longComputation = for ints $ \n -> tell [show n] >> yield n

twoSmallComputations :: MonadWriter [String] m => Producer Int m ()
twoSmallComputations = do
  longComputation >-> P.take 10
  longComputation >-> P.take 10

main = do
  let (res, log') = runWriter $ P.toListM twoSmallComputations
  mapM_ print log'
```

Here, `ints` is an infinite stream that yields `Int`-s. `longComputation` iterates over the output of `ints` and adds the `Writer` effect. `twoSmallComputations` is a composite stream that first runs `longComputation >-> P.take 10` to exhaustion, then runs it once again.

`mapM_ print log'` now prints just the expected 20 numbers.

See the excellent [pipes tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.5/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html) for further reference.

Comment: This is the proper answer. I should have come up with a `pipes` example but got too entangled in the debate above to actually say something useful :)